# Trying to implement encryption across entire database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a fairly large web app that doesn't currently encrypt any of the data it stores (except for passwords and a few tokens) in the mysql database.  There are quite a few items that get stored and retrieved in the database.  I was wondering if there is some way I can automatically encrypt everything that gets stored to the database and then automatically decrypt whenever anything gets retrieved from the database.  The best option I have right now is to put this in my routes.php file:

```
View::composer('Crypt', function($view){
    $view->with('Crypt', Crypt::class);
});
```

and then manually change every single time the web app makes a call to the database in every Controller, Model, and View, like changing:

```
$user->email = Input::get('email');
```

to

```
$user->email = Crypt::encode(Input::get('email));
```

and then every time I retrieve database values (which is a lot) do:

```
{{Crypt::decode($user->email)}}
```

I feel like there must be an easier way to do this than manually literally 1000 times, but I am not sure how.

Comment: how about SSL/TLS and a physically secure server. I mean a cert thru a CA is like $10/yr. So let's see, that is 1/2 cup of coffee less, per month. Problem solved

Comment: @Drew how does that encrypt data in the database?

Comment: What is the purpose to encrypt everything. It will consume resources for nothing. Except passwords, the other fields are usually not encrypted in a db. Also, if you have a way to decrypt the encoded datas, it's useless. If you wanna crypt datas, you should uses hash but datas will not be readable, you could only do comparisons.

Comment: @gview I never said it did. This is the peanut gallery section. To defend your idea is the below section, called Answers

Comment: It may be possible to use eloquent mutators, you can use them to encrypt/decrypt any fields when inserting/retrieving.

Comment: @Drew, you were the one who stated in your comment "Problem solved."  The question posed in a nutshell, and I quote:  " I was wondering if there is some way I can automatically encrypt everything that gets stored to the database and then automatically decrypt whenever anything gets retrieved from the database."  I guess you didn't bother to read it, or you're just trolling?

Comment: I mostly agree with reflex.  I have a hard time understanding why you would want to do this, given the enormous cost, and inevitability that you'll disable most of the benefits of using a relational data store.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I appreciate all the comments.  It might be a good compromise in this situation to only manually encrypt a few sensitive fields.  The problem is that whoever the software engineers are working on this project (myself included) will get access to the database, which does reveal private information in at least a few of the fields, but some fields are more private than others.  I'm interested in hearing more about the idea @Jeemusu proposed re: "eloquent mutators" as this is not an area I know much about.

Comment: @user3089840 if you plan to work with several developers, maybe it's better to fill the whole db with fake datas. If the datas will be encrypted into db, will the developers able to work with that db if they don't have the key to decrypt datas?

Comment: @user3089840 Accessors & Mutators would work well for encrypting a few sensitive columns. As others have said, I would be very weary of encrypting your **entire** database.

Comment: @zeflex I don't mind them having the key.  It's just too much personal information available while glancing at phpmyadmin.  Your idea of filling the db with fake data might work.

Comment: @gview, get serious. I don't troll. It could be an XY Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... perhaps he doesn't want his data read over the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having to repeatedly use `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods each time you make a call to the database, you could instead use Eloquents [Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators).

## Defining An Accessor

> To define an accessor, create a getFooAttribute method on your model
>   where Foo is the "camel" cased name of the column you wish to access.
>   In this example, we'll define an accessor for the first_name
>   attribute. The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when
>   attempting to retrieve the value of first_name:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Decrypt the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return Crypt::decode($value);
    }
}
```

## Defining A Mutator

> To define a mutator, define a setFooAttribute method on your model
>   where Foo is the "camel" cased name of the column you wish to access.
>   So, again, let's define a mutator for the first_name attribute. This
>   mutator will be automatically called when we attempt to set the value
>   of the first_name attribute on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Encrypt the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = Crypt::encode($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might work.  I'll accept your answer if it does.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: Create another attribute for encrypted attribute. E.g: to access `email` attribute, use `email_encrypted`. That way, you don't find yourself going back and forth on encrypts/decrypts in your application.

Source: Currently encrypting all IDs on forms in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [CryptDB](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb).

It does database encryption while allowing you to still perform queries securely on the encrypted data.

Although you will need to add support for laravel yourself.